# Making GAC assembly to load custom assembly

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-assembly

My application has a dll that will be invoked by .NET framework assemblies that reside in Global Assembly Cache. This perfectly works in a local machine.

I am facing issue in Azure Web app. In Azure web apps, I couldn't add my assembly to GAC. So whenever the GAC dlls(System.dll,System.Xml.dll,..etc) tries to load my assembly it fails by throwing file not found exception. But in the same process my assembly got loaded into different Application domain /LM/2/... and not in AppDomain "EE Shared Assembly Repository".

```
  var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New AppDomain", null, new AppDomainSetup
        {
            CachePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.CachePath,
            ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
            LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.SingleDomain //tried MultiDomain too
        });
```

By some code as above,  I tried creating an AppDomain with different configurations and loaderoptimization sets and loaded the assembly into it, so that the System.dll can find and load my assembly. But that too dint work out.

How can i make my assembly(that is present in %home%\wwwroot\bin) get loaded into the dlls that are present in GAC..?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set `ApplicationBase` and `PrivateBinPath` on the `AppDomainSetup` object so it knows where to load your assemblies from.

Comment: The appdomain is loading my assembly. But the problem here is the assemblies in GAC couldn't find my dll. (i.e) while my assembly code get executed in System.Web.dll and System.Data.dll, I am getting filenotfound exception saying couldnt find my dll.